# How to load a specific page as the initial page in Node-Red?

Tags: powershell, node-red

I have 2 tabs in my Node-Red dashboard. I initiate my nodered dashboard from the power shell script like this.

```
# Go to NodeRed Dashboard
Start-Process "http://localhost:1880/ui"
```

This is always shows tab 1. How can I display tab 2 at initial time when PowerShell script calls this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the page number on the end of the URL

e.g.

- `http://localhost:1880/ui/#!/0` is the first page
- `http://localhost:1880/ui/#!/1` is the second page